# how to grab next-in-line integers from list python

Tags: python

So i have these 2 lists:

```py
list1 = [81, 68, 53, 28, 19, 7, 2, 0]
```

list1 is fine and nothing would need to happen as there's no numbers (1 up, or 1 below) from any of the nums in list.

```py
list2 = [68, 67, 53, 21, 20, 19, 9, 7, 1, 0]
```

Whereas in list2 i have (68,67) (21,20,19) & (1,0)

How can i have a new list be filled with the "extra"(starting from high) next-in-line numbers?

It may or may not be important but just to point out that the list2 will always be sorted from high to low before reaching the below code.

Here's what ive got so far:

```py
####################################################
list2 = [68, 67, 53, 21, 20, 19, 9, 7, 1, 0]
numbs_list= []
complete = False
i = 0
# start = 0
# end = len(list2) -1
while complete is False:
    if len(list2) > 1:
        # if index 1 is next-in-line to index 0
        # if 67 == 67(68 -1)
        if list2[i +1] == list2[i] -1:

            # add 68 to numbs list
            numbs_list.append(list2[i])

            # remove 68 from list2
            list2.pop(list2.index(list2[i]))
        else:
            list2.pop(list2.index(list2[i]))
    else:
        complete = True

    # start += 1
    # if start == end:
    #     complete = True

# from list2 this is what i need numbs_list to have stored once the while loop is done:
numbs_list = [68, 21, 20, 1]
# whats left in list2 does not matter after the numbs_list is finalised as list2 will eventually get cleared and repopulated.
####################################################
```

"next-in-line" may be the wrong wording but i think you get the idea of what i mean. if not here's some examples:

```
1,0
11,10,9
23,22
58,57
91,90,89,88
```

notice how theres no room between any & all of those nums? because theyre all next-in-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try iterating through each index and comparing it to the index - 1. and append the index to the extra list if they are only 1 apart

```py
list2 = [68, 67, 53, 21, 20, 19, 9, 7, 1, 0]
extra = []
for i in range(1,len(list2)):
    if list2[i-1] == list2[i] + 1:
        extra.append(list2[i-1])
print(extra)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
list2 = [68, 67, 53, 21, 20, 19, 9, 7, 1, 0]
extra = [list2[i-1] for i in range(1,len(list2)) if list2[i-1] == list2[i]+ 1]
print(extra)
```

Output

```
[68, 21, 20, 1]
```

Comment: hi, ty for your quick response/help. much appreciated.

p.s is there any way the 'extra' list could be put into a list comprehension?
many thanks.

Comment: @PhilGibson  Pleas see updated answer for list comprehension

Comment: tyvm sir.
Appreciated :)

Comment: Nice.  To be nit-picky, will chose different name - ```prev = L[i-1]``` in the for-loop...  To make the intent clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have made this far more complicated than it needs to be.  Just remember what the last number was, and if the new number is one below it, then add it to your lists.

```
list2 = [68, 67, 53, 21, 20, 19, 9, 7, 1, 0]
maybe = []
last = -99
curr = []
for n in list2:
    if n == last-1:
        maybe[-1].append(n)
    else:
        maybe.append( [n] )
    last = n
numbs_list = [k for k in maybe if len(k) > 1]
print(numbs_list)
```

Comment: hi, ty tim for your efforts.
i decided to mark @Alexander's answer as the best answer due to your answer returning list within list like so: [[68, 67], [21, 20, 19], [1, 0]].

whereas i just needed: [68, 21, 20, 1].

regards.

Comment: You could achieve those results by adding three characters:  `numbs_list = [k[0] for k in maybe if len(k) > 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

This was fun with `functools.reduce`. Pun definitely intended.

```py
from functools import reduce

lst = [68, 67, 53, 21, 20, 19, 9, 7, 1, 0]

lst2 = reduce(
  lambda acc, x: 
    [[x]] if len(acc) == 0 else 
    acc[:-1]+[acc[-1]+[x]] if len(acc[-1]) != 0 and acc[-1][-1] == x+1 else 
    acc+[[x]],
  lst, 
  []
)
# [[68, 67], [53], [21, 20, 19], [9], [7], [1, 0]]
```

Once we have this, everything else you might want to figure out is trivial.

```py
lst3 = [y for x in lst2 for y in x if len(x) == 1]
# [53, 9, 7]

lst4 = [x[:-1] for x in lst2 if len(x) > 1]
# [[68], [21, 20], [1]]

lst5 = [y for x in lst2 for y in x[:-1] if len(x) > 1]
# [68, 21, 20, 1]
```

We might also implement a general purpose `split_when` function and use that rather than `functools.reduce`.

```py
def split_when(lst, pred):
    if len(lst) == 0: return
    last = lst[0]
    lst2 = [last]
    for x in lst[1:]:
        if pred(last, x):
            yield lst2
            lst2 = [x]
            last = x
        else:
            lst2.append(x)
            last = x
    if len(lst2) > 0: 
        yield lst2

lst2 = list(split_when(lst, lambda a, b: a - b > 1))
# [[68, 67], [53], [21, 20, 19], [9], [7], [1, 0]]
```